# Monitor open file handles in Java - OS-independent

Tags: java, io, inputstream, monitoring, filehandle

my issue is to monitor open file handles in java and being independent from the type of OS (Linux, Windows, etc)

My Application is a web based server application running with tomcat and Java8.

For a possible solution only the Java-Language itself and both, *Guava* and *Apache Commons*, are to be considered as my company does not allow the use of any other third party libraries.

Any suggestions on how to do that? I already thought of inheriting an `InputStream` and injecting some stuff into its  `open()` and `close()` methods but this is not really whats I consider a "good" solution...

I'd be very thankful for your help!

Comment: Are you interesting in open file descriptor count? In case of count you can use java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getOpenFileDescriptorCount(). Is it enough for you?

Comment: Well I tried that already, but the compiler complains about `getOpenFileDescriptorCount()` not to be found. I found a sollution for Linux elsewhere where they casted `getOperatingSystemMXB‌​ean()` to a UnixOSMXBean, but there was no equivalent for other operating systems.
But thank you for replying

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/lib-file-leak-detector can do this provided you have enough control of the environment to pass `-javaagent`. It would not be appropriate to run in production.

Comment: A terrific tool. I would definitely recommend. This helped me to solve a major production issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you don't really like seems to be the best one, you can simply emit a message, for example through an EventBus (you have it in Guava), whenever you open or close a file. Your `ManagedFileInputStream` has just to call `enventBus.post(someFilePointer)` and `super.open()` or `super.close()`
.

But there are many other file that could be opened by your application (jar files,  web resources like css , images, scripts, temporary file created by tomcat , temporary files created by the JVM).

I think that there is no sensible way to monitor all file opened by a java application from within the java Application, maybe that's something for the OS to manage.

Comment: As I'm dealing with `URL.openStream()` this would force me to rewrite a big part of `java.net.URL` and its components. Unfortunately this is killing my time resources and blowing up the rest of the product... Seems like I have to capitulate and tell my boss its not doable with affordable complexity